Eclipse cannot start (XstartOnFirstThread)
I am learning to use Eclipse IDE right now.
I am using MacBook M1, Sonoma 14.4.1
Previously I am using Eclipse fine, but suddenly after not using it for about 1 week, it cannot boot up.
In this 1 week I don't remember changing anything big.
Every time I tried to run it, it closed before even land into the first screen. It dropped in the middle of loading screen.
I tried to run it in terminal, and got a message below.
./eclipse -clean
2024-05-02 10:15:51.560 eclipse[1725:23581] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
May 02, 2024 10:15:55 AM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle ch.qos.logback.classic
10:15:58.790 [Start Level: Equinox Container: e184951f-302b-438d-bcaa-7b4c398c21a2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.util.ShutdownHook -- register org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FileStoreAttributes$$Lambda$180/0x000000001726e3f8@4fd63d35 with shutdown hook
10:15:58.790 [Start Level: Equinox Container: e184951f-302b-438d-bcaa-7b4c398c21a2] DEBUG org.eclipse.jgit.internal.util.ShutdownHook -- register org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FileStoreAttributes$$Lambda$180/0x000000001726e3f8@4fd63d35 with shutdown hook
WARNING: Annotation classes from the 'javax.inject' or 'javax.annotation' package found.
It is recommended to migrate to the corresponding replacements in the jakarta namespace.
The Eclipse E4 Platform will remove support for those javax-annotations in a future release.
To suppress this warning, set the VM property: -Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
To disable processing of 'javax' annotations entirely, set the VM property: -Declipse.e4.inject.javax.disabled=true

***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread

But, in my eclipse.ini, the XstartOnFirstThread argument are already written.
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.600.v20231106-1826.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.2.800.v20231003-1442
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_17.0.10.v20240120-1143/jre/lib/libjli.dylib
-vmargs
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.log.file=/Users/eclipse_log
-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.osgi.logger.bundleLog
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=false
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=5
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=25
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
-javaagent:lombok.jar

So after I checked the eclipse.ini and make sure the argument are there, I run the eclipse again but same error occur.
What is the problem? And how to fix it?
Any help will be appreciated.

You have an outdated Eclipse installation with Lombok installed. Does a fresh Eclipse installation work? If you start Eclipse without -javaagent:lombok.jar and with a fresh workspace (./eclipse -clean -data path/to/workspace), does it work then or if not, will a .metadata/.log file created in the new workspace?

Thank you for the answer!
I tried to remove lombok and new workspace, its working.
And I tried to add lombok back, using the new workspace, its working as well.
So the problem is in the workspace? is it possible to fix the old workspace, because if possible i want to keep all the setting

Please try in your old workspace to delete or better rename the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi which stores the current layout.

where can I find this file? is it in Eclipse package(in the Application)?

This file is not in the installation directory, but in your workspace (see File > Switch Workspace > Other...).
